# Custom list Adapter and AsyncTask

Tags: android, custom-adapter

Just having an issue with a custom Adapter for a `ListFragment`.
The `AsyncTask` returns the Array of objects to the `ListFragment`, which instantiate a custom adapter passing the context, the layout to inflate and the data (the array of object).
But at runtime, I get a `NullPointerException` at the `getCount()` method of my custom adapter because `mData` is null.

Does anyone know how to deal with it? How to `"properly"` pass the data to the `customAdapter`?

Thx!

**AsyncTask onPostExecute():**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Listing[] listings) {
    if (listings != null) {

        ListingFragment.mListings = listings;

    }
}
```

**ListingFragment:**

```
public class ListingFragment extends ListFragment {

public static ItemAdapter mAdapter;
public static Listing[] mListings;

// Constructor
public ListingFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FetchListing task = new FetchListing();
    String query = getArguments().getString("test");
    if (query != null) {
        task.execute(query);
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_row, mListings);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

**ItemAdapter**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
int mLayoutResourceId;
Listing mData[];

// Constructor
public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Listing[] data) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mData = data;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    Listing listingItem = mData[position];

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listItem = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

    ImageView listingItemImageView = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.listing_item_icon);
    TextView listingItemTextView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.listing_item_name);

    listingItemImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listingItem.getUrl()));
    listingItemTextView.setText(listingItem.getTitle());

    return listItem;
}
}
```

Comment: Your fragment is `ListingFragment`.  So you need to change here from `ListFragment.mListings = listings;` to `ListingFragment.mListings = listings;`

Comment: So just move this  `mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_row, mListings);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);` line to in `onPostExecute()` method because `UI` will be updated in that method and in `onCreate()` method your `mListings` is null.

Comment: The AsyncTask is in a separate class so cant call getActivity() or setListAdapter()

Comment: So you need to make a constructor for your `AsyncTask` in which your context will be pass and while you call your asynctask in activity then need to use context with `YourActivityName.this`.

Comment: Then no way to call the setListAdapter().
And simply calling it in the ListFragment onCreate() passing the adapter doesnt work. I just get a spinner that never stops loading

Comment: Then you can pass another boolean parameter and make it true in `onPostExecute()` method and while in listfragment  its being executed in `onCreate()` while you `setListAdapter` check it with condition like if it is true then set your list adapter.

Comment: Ok so the problem is that the Listing[] never gets to the ListingFragment in the onCreate()

Comment: yes. it is... and initialiy it is null.

Comment: So how to populate it from the onPostExecute()?

Comment: Read my last second comment....

Comment: Doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Then make your asynctask inner class in your listfragment